# "Auth fail" in jsch-0.1.42 with Java 1.4.2

Tags: java, jsch

I have this simple Java program that uses [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect to an SFTP server.

The connection fails with an "Auth fail" exception on Java 1.4.2, but it connects flawlessly on Java 1.7.

```
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    jsch.setKnownHosts(KNOWN_HOSTS_PATH);
    jsch.addIdentity(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, PASSPHRASE);

    Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, HOSTNAME, 22);
    session.connect(2500);

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
    channel.setInputStream(System. in );
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
    channel.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

The key I'm using is an `ssh-rsa 4096` bit key. The `.pub` key file exists in the same directory as the private key.

When connecting a logger, I see the following messages before the exception (which occurs on `channel.connect();`):

```
INFO: Connecting to <redacted> port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.42
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: arcfour is not available.
INFO: arcfour128 is not available.
INFO: arcfour256 is not available.
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
INFO: Host '<redacted>' is known and mathces the RSA host key
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Disconnecting from <redacted> port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:452)
        at TestJsch.main(TestJsch.java:19)
```

When I run the same program with Java 1.7, it says

```
INFO: Connecting to <redacted> port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.42
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
INFO: Host '<redacted>' is known and mathces the RSA host key
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT receivedINFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Linux <redacted> 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 13 16:29:33 UTC 2011 x86_64

<server welcome message follows>
```

I have installed the Java Cryptography Extensions (JCE) for the 1.4 VM.

What could be the source of that problem?

Comment: did you notice that it skips the publickey authentication and goes straight to password auth? : Authentications that can continue: password

Comment: @oers Yes, I did. I have no explanation, other than the assumption that some part of the key authentication fails silently (for example because the key is too long or a precondition was not met) and it skips to the next available method without issuing a warning. *"Java 1.4 does not support 4096 bit keys because XYZ"* is answer I would be willing to accept (even though I really can't imagine right now that this could be true).

Comment: Looking at the `UserAuthPublicKey.java` from `JSch`, it looks like this process really does emit little useful information. I suggest compiling JSch from source, and adding more output to that class, so you get an idea as to what's going on, where things fail.

Comment: @MvG I could do that,but digging into a library I know next-to-nothing about doesn't really appeal to me. :/ I've seen the author of Jsch around SO, I was hoping he'd show up.

Comment: @Tomalak Looking over the JSch source, UserAuthPublicKey.java and IdentityFile.java actually already include a number of commented out `System.err.println()` debugging statements, so maybe just re-enabling those would be enough to shed light on why (or at least where) things are failing.

Comment: @blahdiblah Yes, I think that's what I have to do. Too bad I won't get my +100 bounty back if I answer my own question. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, but don't worry.  I'm sure that if you *really* apply yourself then maybe *someday*, in the far distant future, you'll have managed to earn *most* of it back and can put a bounty on another question. :)

Comment: By looking at the source code (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/jcraft/jsch/UserAuthPublicKey.java.html, line 122), it seems it comes from `identity.isEncrypted()` which returns true. By looking to the identity var (constructor of http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/jcraft/jsch/IdentityFile.java.html), the `encrypted` is not set to false, so as you already did, I also suspect that the JDK 1.4 does not handle your RSA key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has a limitation for using strong crypto algorithm. Check content of `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/US_Export_policy.jar` and `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/local_policy.jar`. If you find something like this:

```
// File: default_local.policy
// Some countries have import limits on crypto strength.
// This policy file is worldwide importable.
grant {
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DES", 64;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DESede", *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC2", 128,
                   "javax.crypto.spec.RC2ParameterSpec", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC4", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC5", 128,
          "javax.crypto.spec.RC5ParameterSpec", *, 12, *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RSA", 2048;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission *, 128;
};
```

Decision is to download and install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy. Previously, it was located on Sun's site, now I don't know where it can be found.

You can read more [in this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=11)

EDIT:
After some research, I found my answer was incorrect.

Java 1.4 does not support RSA keys more than 2048 byte length [BUG 4524097](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4524097)

Comment: I *have* installed the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy. If you look again at my question, you will find that I said that.

Comment: sorry, look on your question again and see only "Java Cryptography Extensions (JCE)", what is not the same as "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy" to me.

Comment: Okay, then I have not been clear enough (the Sun/Oracle terminology for this nonsense is confusing). I have installed this: [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#7503-jce-1.4.2-oth-JPR). I'm also pretty sure there is no other file with a similar name but a different effect.

Comment: Hm. To enable strong cryptography in 1.4 you need two packages: JCE - it is optional package (not shipped by default) with algorithm implementations, what provides _ability_ of using cryptography, and JCE Unlimited Policy, what eliminate restrictions for some algorithm, such as RSA with 4096 key. Are you shure you have both of them installed? I belive you have installed JCE, because if it not, you cannot use criptography at all, but have missed JCE Policy.

Comment: Okay, then let's do it the other way around. Can you make a simple, definitive list of files that I must install and the locations I must install them to?

Comment: first: **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) 1.2.2** and second: **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 1.4.2**. Download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html, unzip and follow instruction in INSTALL.html and Readme.txt.

Comment: So even though I'm pretty sure that this is unnecessary, I now have installed the `jce1_2_2.jar` file to the `jre/lib/ext` directory of the Java VM and made sure that the local security policy allows access to that file. I think that was unnecessary since `sunjce_provider.jar` already existed and apparently contains the necessary cryptographic algorithms, so as of Java 1.4 there is no need to install an extra library. As expected, adding the JCE 1.2 library chanced nothing. The error is still there.

Comment: @Tomalak maybe my english isn't perfect, i'm not a native speaker. You don't understand what i trying to say, and i don't know how to say it in different words. Sorry for wasting your time. Bye.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your English (why do you think that?). I'm not a native speaker myself. I just tried to be as specific as possible about what I did and about my reasoning. I did not intend to sound annoyed/irritated. Sorry if I made that impression.

Comment: ok, after some research i found this is a bug, and it was resolved only in java 5. My previous answer was not eligible for this particular case. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4524097. Updated answer.

Comment: This is fantastic Info. Thanks for digging that up. :) I'm gonna set up a bounty on the question and accept your answer as soon as it's technically possible to do so.

Comment: @Tomalak at-user1516873 Just want to add that this is good research ... even after more than 2 year, I dug this up to solve my specific problem. I am also glad to see that there is great respect and patience. (sorry for this me-to, but thought it had a place here in this case).

Answer (score 3):

My problems with jsch have been around permissions.  So i would do the following to eliminate them as problems

1. Make sure you can ssh to the remote on the command line using the
   generated keys.
2. Pass in the password and make sure you can get a connection to the remote.
3. Check the permissions on the directory locally and on the remote [good ssh summary](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/).
4. Try using the local host as a remote.

Failing that download the source code and step though it in a debug session.

Comment: Points 1 to 3 are covered by the fact that connecting with Java 1.7 works. I'm using the same `.class` file just in a different VM. Strictly speaking, this makes point 4 obsolete as well.

Comment: do you know which error it is throwing? if it is a JSchException -- catch it directly and print out the string can be informative. (same with the JSchPartialAuthException).

Comment: This question is answered in the first of the two printouts in my answer. But if you think catching it directly will make any difference, I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: the last time i worked with this library it normally printed out some error codes that could be mapped directly to problems.  But I only figured that out when I downloaded the source and stepped through it.  if you have a look in Session.java you will see what i mean (i was looking at version 0.148). adding a print for e.getMessage() i think may do the same thing.  The thing is I would need the actual error rather than the wrapped stack trace before i can really add any value. good luck

Comment: Yeah, I had hoped to avoid that. Maybe I just use a shell call to a command line executable and be done with it. Depends on whether my curiosity gets the better of me. It's not a matter of life or death in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an Open SSH key? jsch uses Open SSH key formats. You can convert your existing one to an Open SSH format. This is how: Use putty keygen and load your existing key. You may be prompted to enter your password to decrypt it. After that click on the conversions option above and choose the "Export OpenSSH Key". Use this newly generated key in your program above.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If there was something wrong with the key file format it wouldn't work on Java 1.7.

Answer (score -2):

**This code works fine...**

```
public class Exec2 {

static String SSH_SERVER_PATH = "localhost";
static String SSH_SERVER_USERNAME = "root";
static String SSH_SERVER_PASSWORD = "root";

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String host = SSH_SERVER_PATH;
        String user = SSH_SERVER_USERNAME;

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

        // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.

        UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
        session.setUserInfo(ui);
        session.connect();

        String command = "uname";

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

        channel.setInputStream(null);

        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

    String passwd;

    public String getPassword() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
        return true;
    }


    public String getPassphrase() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
        passwd = SSH_SERVER_PASSWORD;
        return true;
    }

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("message = " + message);
    }

    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
            String name, String instruction, String[] prompt, boolean[] echo) {
        if (prompt[0].equals("Password: ")){
            String[] response = new String[1];
            response[0] = SSH_SERVER_PASSWORD;
            return response;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> public String getPassphrase() {
>           return null;
>       }
>
> ```
> public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
>     return true;
> }
>
> public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
>     passwd = SSH_SERVER_PASSWORD;
>     return true;
> }
>
> public void showMessage(String message) {
>     System.out.println("message = " + message);
> ```