# Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail with sftp private key

Tags: java, sftp, spring-integration

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="file:${keyfile}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${user}" />
        <property name="port" value="${port}" />
</bean>
```

I have the above configuration. and I have public key under authorized keys ~/.ssh2 on server. I am still getting the **Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail** error. All the credentials are correct and am able to sftp through command prompt. Kindly suggest asap. Confused.
Please see the logs:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 |   ... 21 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 | Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 |   at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:464)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 |   at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:158)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 |   at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:198)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/31 13:41:23 |   ... 22 more
```

This is the detailed log. Iam Confused whether it is connecting or not. Could you please help me

Comment: How have you verified that the correct key file is in the right place and the correct value has been substituted for `${keyfile}`?  There are lots of places in that chain that could be broken.

Comment: I have posted the log below. Could you please help me to understand why this Auth error, as i could see Poll resulted in Message: null as well after the error. Confused with the logs

Comment: @user_1003 don't post additional information in an answer - instead *edit your question* to provide additional details. Have a read through this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: HI Jim. Can u please respond . Please suggest me. I have pasted my logs below. As it dint allow me to paste logs in comment,I had to put them under Answer.Please suggest

Comment: Thanks Jeen, Sory about that, I have deleted the logs form Answers and put them in my question as u suggested. Thanks :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Integration / JSch: Auth fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154361/spring-integration-jsch-auth-fail)

Comment: Just checked the link. But seems like it is not answered and i couldn't find any resolution there. AM i missing anything!.Please let me know.

Comment: Someone has any suggesions/answers for this. Please respond. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I got it resolved. It is picking up wrong user ID. checked server logs. and resolved it. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

Turn on `DEBUG` logging for JSCH as [discussed in the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging). It should help you track it down.